# Xcode Swift, access to internal data

Tags: swift, core-location

I'm new to Xcode and Swift development, but I'm looking at `CoreData.CLGeocoder.geocodeAddressString`

I'm able to geocode an address, but what I'd like to see are the types of data that it returns.  As am example:

```
let geoCoder = CLGeocoder();
geoCoder.geocodeAddressString("123 Fake Street...")
...
```

I'm able to extract out the `CLPlacemark` from this method, but I'm not sure if/how I can access it's properties.

For example:

`CLPlacemark._internal.geoMapItemStorage._placeData._components[0]._type` = 41

Using the Xcode debugger, I'm able to print a description of this object, and it reports

```
type = "COMPONENT_TYPE_TEXT_BLOCK"
```

Now I'm guessing that this has come from an enum (or similar) somewhere, but I don't seem to have access to this. Or if I do, I'm not sure how to do it.

Is this a limitation with the SDK, or am I just doing it wrong?

Comment: You definitely should not be navigating the internals of this object. This method takes a completion handler, which is an optional array of `CLPlacemark` objects (and an `Error`, if any). Use that.

Comment: Well let's just say that I want to navigate the internals of it, is there a way of accessing where the resolution of type=41 comes from?

Comment: Not that I know of. Probably needless to say, but as a general rule, private implementation details are not documented and, if discovered, (a) aren’t reliable; and (b) can’t/shouldn’t be used in apps distributed via the App Store. We have access to source for a few things like Swift libraries and libDispatch, but not most of these frameworks, such as CoreLocation.

Comment: @Rob can you help us here ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66634089/arithmetic-calculations-with-fields-of-coredata-models-using-nspredicate