# CoreData NSPredicate for Arithmetic calculations in Swift Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, core-location, nspredicate

How can i write an Sql query in swift CoreData using NSpredicate for the problem below, i want to find locations within a range based on some fields in the location model:

The fields below are pre-calculated before the query.

```
    let CUR_cos_lat = cos(currenLocation.latitude * .pi / 180)
    let CUR_sin_lat = sin(currenLocation.latitude * .pi / 180)
    let CUR_cos_lng = cos(currenLocation.longitude * .pi / 180)
    let CUR_sin_lng = sin(currenLocation.longitude * .pi / 180)
    let cos_allowed_distance = cos(2.0 / 6371)
```

i want to write a query like the below in Swift CoreData using  NSPredicate:

```
SELECT * FROM position WHERE CUR_sin_lat * sin_lat + CUR_cos_lat * cos_lat * (cos_lng* 
CUR_cos_lng + sin_lng * CUR_sin_lng) > cos_allowed_distance;
```

The fields below in the query above are already available in the CoreData model,

1. sin_lat
2. cos_lat
3. cos_lng
4. sin_lng
5. cos_allowed_distance

This is what i tried but did not return any locations,what is wrong with my expression

```
 let predicateS = NSPredicate(format: "(%f * trignometry.sinLat + %f) * trignometry.cosLat * (trignometry.cosLng * %f + trignometry.sinLng * %f ) > %f",CUR_sin_lat,CUR_cos_lat,CUR_cos_lng,CUR_sin_lng,cos_allowed_distance)
```

Comment: What have you tried, what does your current predicate look like? Maybe I am missing something but it doesn’t look that complicated to solve this.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson , Apologies i've updated the question. With the solution for this i can solve all similar problems

Comment: The expressions in the SQLand the predicate are slightly different: the predicate has parenthesis around "(%f * trignometry.sinLat + %f)" which the SQL does not.

Comment: @pbasdf , Thank you , but after removing the parenthesis nothing really changed